# which is more accurate: "variable" or "parameter"?

Tags: python, terminology

I'd like to settle an argument I've got about some vocabulary.
So I was asked this question:
What is the value of the variable x at the end of the execution of the following script:

```
def f(x):
  x = x + 1
  return x + 1


x = 0
f(x+1)
```

I chose to say 0, because I think that the word *variable* is more accurate when describing the global scope x than when talking about the parameter x, inside the f function. My teacher said he expected 2 as an answer because the x variable takes a value of 2 inside the function. My reasoning is that he sould've used the word parameter instead of variable, and also that he mentioned *at the end of the execution of the following **script*** and and not function.
I'm thus asking here for people's thoughts.

Comment: Simple: `print(x)` - there is only one x and that one has the value 0.

Comment: If teacher wanted anything else they should have put a `print(x)` and `print(f(x+1))` into the code and asked for what is printed, clearing up any ambiguity on their part. But `0` is absolutely the only correct answer as currently phrased.

Comment: At the end of the execution the stack frame of f(x) is deleted. There is only the global `x` and the function `f`. The value of the global `x` is 0. Also the line `x=x+1` is redundant as you can just return `x+2`

Answer (score 3):

There are two *variables* `x` in the script. One local variable `x` inside the function and one global variable `x` outside of it.

As @Tom McLean said in the comment above, by the end of the script, the local variable `x` does not exist anymore. So you were correct in saying that the variable x's value was  0.

I don't think the word 'parameter' would've been correct since a parameter only defines what *arguments* a function can accept. See [What is the difference between arguments and parameters?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-is-the-difference-between-arguments-and-parameters).

Once an argument has been passed to a function, it is assigned to a local *variable*. From the [argument docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument):

> Arguments are assigned to the named local variables in a function body.

Comment: It's common (and generally entirely acceptable!) to refer to the `x` in that function as a "parameter". It's *also* a local variable but, contrary to what you wrote, calling it a "parameter" is also correct (it doesn't cease being a parameter just because it's a local variable). The rest of the answer is spot-on.